# How can I use Meteor simple schema with meteor-pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, pagination

Just started playing around with Meteor and I'm looking to making the `meteor-simple-schema` work with `meteor-pages`

The principle is simple, I'm just playing around with the example `todos` app they provide and wanted to add infinity scroll to load more todos. But I can't get both to work.

Here is my code for the default `meteor-simple-schema`

```
Todos = new Meteor.Collection('todos', {});
Schema = {};
Todos.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        label: "Name",
        max: 200,
        min: 2
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Created",
        optional: false
    },
    creatorId: {
        type: String,
        label: "Creator",
        optional: false
    },
    done: {
        type: Boolean,
        defaultValue: false,
        label: "Done?",
        optional: true
    }        
}));
```

Then I switched the `new Meteor.Collection('todos')` to `new Meteor.Pages('todos')` and even `new Meteor.Pagination('todos')`

But then the schema creates errors. How can I make both work?

Here are the errors:

```
W20150317-22:47:23.197(1)? (STDERR) ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.azxhr5++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20150317-22:47:23.197(1)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20150317-22:47:23.197(1)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20150317-22:47:23.199(1)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object #<Pages> has no method 'attachSchema'
W20150317-22:47:23.200(1)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/todos.js:25:7
W20150317-22:47:23.200(1)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/todos.js:60:3
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is quite old question, but maybe someone else is still looking for answer.

To use meteor-pages pagination with collection2 you just need to pass the collection object for the Meteor.Pagination.

example:

```
var Customers = new Mongo.Collection("customers");

var Schemas = {};
Schemas.Customer = new SimpleSchema({ … });
Customers.attachSchema(Schemas.Customer);

var pages = new Meteor.Pagination(Customers, { … });
```

Answer (score 0):

did you change it to new Meteor.Pages or Meteor.Pagination?

can you post what issues the schema is creating?

instead of

```
    TODOS = new Meteor.Collection('todos');
```

try it with

```
    TODOS = new Mongo.Collection('todos');
```

it looks as if that could be what you may need.

Comment: Updated the main question with the error logs. And to answer your first question, I tried both and it gives the same error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me you didn't add [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) package to your app - this is where the `attachSchema` method is defined. The following command should resolve the issue.

```
meteor add aldeed:collection2
```